# How to fix unknown login after multiple atemps

Tags: python

When I log in as an "existing user", it works perfectly when I log in first try
But in the while loop, when I get the login incorrect and it prompts me again and THEN I get the login correct, it comes up as login failed

```py
import sys
existing = " "
possibleAnswersExisting = ["y","n"]
accountFileW = open("AccountFile.txt","a")
accountFileR = open("AccountFile.txt","r")
while existing not in possibleAnswersExisting:
    existing = input("Are you an already existing user? (Please input y/n)\n>>")
    if existing not in possibleAnswersExisting:
        print('Please enter a valid answer. (Only "y" or "n")')
def register():
    username = input("What would you like your username to be?")
    password = input("What would you like your password to be?")
    print("Welcome" ,username + "! Make sure to remember your password or write it down in case your forget!")
    accountFileW.writelines([username, " ", password, "\n"])
def login():
    x = ""
    attempts = 0
    while x != True:
        lusername = input("What is your username? (CaSe SeNsItIvE PleAsE)\n>>")
        lpassword = input("What is your password? (CaSe SeNsItIvE PleAsE)\n>>")
        for line in accountFileR:
            print("in for loop")
            loginInfo = line.split()
            print(loginInfo)
            if lusername == loginInfo[0] and lpassword == loginInfo[1]:
                print("--Successful login, setting x to true")
                x = True
                break
        attempts = attempts + 1
        if str((4 - attempts)) == 0:
            print("Error, login credentials invalid. Exiting program...")
            sys.exit()
        if attempts > 0 and attempts < 5:
            print("Incorrect" ,str((4 - attempts)), "attemptsleft.")
    print("Successful login")

if existing == "n":
    register()
elif existing == "y":
    login()
else:
    print("Error with existing")
    sys.exit()

accountFileW.close()
accountFileR.close()
```

I expect the output for the login to be successful, but it says incorrect unlike when I get it right the first try

Comment: You only open `accountFileR` once, but if you enter the wrong password and have to go round again, the the file will be exhausted. You need to open the file just before you use it. Or use `.seek(0)` to restart from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

After Python has read a file, its "Prompt" is at the end of the file. If you do call read on the fileobject again it will return nothin since there is nothing left to read. 
With seek(x) you can place the "Prompt" to the postion x. In you case 0 since you want to read the file again.

I injected the line on the right place:

```
import sys
existing = " "
possibleAnswersExisting = ["y","n"]
accountFileW = open("AccountFile.txt","a")
accountFileR = open("AccountFile.txt","r")
while existing not in possibleAnswersExisting:
    existing = input("Are you an already existing user? (Please input y/n)\n>>")
    if existing not in possibleAnswersExisting:
        print('Please enter a valid answer. (Only "y" or "n")')
def register():
    username = input("What would you like your username to be?")
    password = input("What would you like your password to be?")
    print("Welcome" ,username + "! Make sure to remember your password or write it down in case your forget!")
    accountFileW.writelines([username, " ", password, "\n"])
def login():
    x = ""
    attempts = 0
    while x != True:
        lusername = input("What is your username? (CaSe SeNsItIvE PleAsE)\n>>")
        lpassword = input("What is your password? (CaSe SeNsItIvE PleAsE)\n>>")

        accountFileR.seek(0) # <----  injected line

        for line in accountFileR:
            print("in for loop")
            loginInfo = line.split()
            print(loginInfo)
            if lusername == loginInfo[0] and lpassword == loginInfo[1]:
                print("--Successful login, setting x to true")
                x = True
                break
        attempts = attempts + 1
        if str((4 - attempts)) == 0:
            print("Error, login credentials invalid. Exiting program...")
            sys.exit()
        if attempts > 0 and attempts < 5:
            print("Incorrect" ,str((4 - attempts)), "attemptsleft.")
    print("Successful login")

if existing == "n":
    register()
elif existing == "y":
    login()
else:
    print("Error with existing")
    sys.exit()

accountFileW.close()
accountFileR.close()
```